# Soap Fault Message Resolver isn't invoked after adding Wss4jSecurityInterceptor config

Tags: spring, webservice-client

I have written a web service client (using Java Spring and JAXB Marshaller) that works with a 3rd party web service. When I send a valid request everything works well. When I send an invalid request then the web service server responds with a SOAP Fault. The client application just fails with a UnmarshallingFailureException

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling 
exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 
unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault").
```

Appears to me that my ws client isn't able to decipher the SOAP fault returned by the web service. I wrote a custom FaultMessageResolver, but it doesn't get invoked (I set a breakpoint there but it doesn't hit. The FaultMessageResolver just worked fine before I added the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor for signature, encryption/decryption stuff). Here's the code:

```
public class VehicleServiceClientExceptionResolver implements FaultMessageResolver {

@Override
public void resolveFault(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {

    SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;

    try {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ErrorMessages.class);
        Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        ErrorMessages errorMessages = (ErrorMessages)unMarshaller.unmarshal(soapMessage.getSoapBody().getFault().getFaultDetail().getDetailEntries().next().getSource());

        if (errorMessages.getErrorMessage().size() > 0) {
            throw new VehicleServiceClientException(errorMessages);
        }

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        LOGGER.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

And this custom soap fault resolver is injected into client side web service template like below:

```
<bean id="vehicleQuotationWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="wsSecurityInterceptor"/>
        </list> 
    </property>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="vehicleQuotationMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="vehicleQuotationMarshaller" />
    <property name="messageSender" ref="urlMessageSender"/>
    <property name="faultMessageResolver" ref="vehicleServiceClientFaultMessageResolver" />
    <property name="defaultUri" value="https://*********/*********Service"/>
</bean>
```

The most weird thing is although I got that unmarshall exception, I did see the encrypted server response was decrypted in my eclipse console when I change the log level from INFO to DEBUG, I am not sure where this DigesterOutputStream comes from, but I think it might be the key to solve this.

Anyone got any idea? Thanks!

```
DEBUG p.xml.dsig.internal.DigesterOutputStream:
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-af090516-9e00-4590-b481-c78e59d6b2fc"><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Client.Validation</faultcode><faultstring</faultstring><detail><em:ErrorMessages xmlns:em="urn:ford/errormessage/v1.0"><em:ErrorMessage><em:ErrorCode>GLSE903100</em:ErrorCode><em:ErrorDescription> CTT System Quote Id already exists ('1041')</em:ErrorDescription><em:ErrorTime>2014-05-16T15:13:20</em:ErrorTime></em:ErrorMessage></em:ErrorMessages></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://nadircode.blogspot.ca/2013/10/handling-soap-fault-in-spring-ws.html): Adding a `WebServiceMessageExtractor<Object>` to:

```
WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(
    new WebServiceMessageCallback(),
    new WebServiceMessageExtractor<Object>())
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
public class ExampleInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
  public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    var resp = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
    Optional.of(resp)
         .filter(res -> !hasFault(res))
         .orElseThrow(() -> new SoapFaultClientException(resp));
    return true;
  }

  private boolean hasFault(final WebServiceMessage response) {
  return Optional.ofNullable(response)
      .filter(resp -> resp instanceof FaultAwareWebServiceMessage)
      .map(resp -> (FaultAwareWebServiceMessage) resp)
      .map(FaultAwareWebServiceMessage::hasFault)
      .orElse(false);
  }
}


@Configuration
public class ExampleConnectorConfig extends WSConnectorConfig
@Bean
  public WSConnector soapConnector(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    var client = new WSConnector(messageFactory());
    client.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{new ExampleInterceptor()});
    client.setDefaultUri(proxy);
    return client;
  }
  //Example
  @Bean
  public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
    SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    messageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return messageFactory;
  }
}
```